# Why is my Power BI line chart not counting my months correctly?

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to figure out why my line chart is counting my months incorrectly.

[image: Power Bi line chart details with source table snippit]

As you can see in the table, I have 6 request dates in January and 4 request dates in February. For some reason the line chart is counting 2 request dates in January and 8 request dates in feb. Almost like it's counting the complete date instead of the request date. But you can see that is not true in the right hand tool bar.

I have tried to summarize and not summarize the date columns from the data source. I've changed the data source to be date. I'm not sure what else to do.

[image: data view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to go out on a limb here and make a wild guess that your calculated column `Month_Name` is based on the date in this `Complete Date` column.

In which case what you see in the visual is perfectly correct, since it would count 8 rows for `Month_Name = "Feb"` and 2 rows for `Month_Name = "Jan"`. The actual value of `Request Date` does not matter at all, just the row count for the chosen dimension value.

Comment: You are right. I started used a date dimensional table instead of using the date column within my table. Silly me. Thank you